# Transactions Rolling Back by default when XACT_ABORT is off

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2014, xact-abort

I have the following transaction

```
BEGIN TRAN
        DECLARE @TransactionAmount MONEY = 5.00
        UPDATE Account SET Balance -= @TransactionAmount WHERE AccountID = 1
        UPDATE Account SET Balance += @TransactionAmount WHERE AccountID = 'blah'
COMMIT TRAN
```

As there is a failure in the second `UPDATE` statement (`AccountID` is an `int` column) and the whole statement is wrapped in a `TRAN` block, the change in the first statement rolls back and the balance for AccountID 1 is not deducted.

As there is no `ROLLBACK` statement in the code above it seems that SQL server does the rollback automatically without the need for an explicit `ROLLBACK` statement

When I looked into it, it seems the automatic rollback behaviour is controlled by a setting called `xact_abort`.

I found the following script online which prints out the settings which are on

```
DECLARE @options INT
SELECT @options = @@OPTIONS

PRINT @options
IF ( (1 & @options) = 1 ) PRINT 'DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK' 
IF ( (2 & @options) = 2 ) PRINT 'IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS' 
IF ( (4 & @options) = 4 ) PRINT 'CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT' 
IF ( (8 & @options) = 8 ) PRINT 'ANSI_WARNINGS' 
IF ( (16 & @options) = 16 ) PRINT 'ANSI_PADDING' 
IF ( (32 & @options) = 32 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS' 
IF ( (64 & @options) = 64 ) PRINT 'ARITHABORT' 
IF ( (128 & @options) = 128 ) PRINT 'ARITHIGNORE'
IF ( (256 & @options) = 256 ) PRINT 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' 
IF ( (512 & @options) = 512 ) PRINT 'NOCOUNT' 
IF ( (1024 & @options) = 1024 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON' 
IF ( (2048 & @options) = 2048 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF' 
IF ( (4096 & @options) = 4096 ) PRINT 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL' 
IF ( (8192 & @options) = 8192 ) PRINT 'NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT' 
IF ( (16384 & @options) = 16384 ) PRINT 'XACT_ABORT'
```

However, when run on my server, `XACT_ABORT` doesn't appear in the printed list so is not switched on.

My question is: what is the need for a `ROLLBACK` statement when it seems that SQL server is doing the rollback automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `XACT_ABORT = OFF` then it is very unpredictable if the transaction rolls back or not. SQL Server sometimes does not, sometimes it does and sometimes it even aborts the batch. (Yes, this does not make any sense.) Other possible outcomes include dooming the transaction or cutting the connection.

In your case you can reliably use `TRY-CATCH` to prevent a rollback and handle the exception.

I found it a good practice to not rely on error processing if possible. Instead, roll back the transaction. Also push error handling into the client if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using transactions it is advisable to set XACT_ABORT = ON at the start of your Stored Procedure.  Erland Sommarskog has an excellent piece on error handling:

http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html